# how to login multiple users with different input in different threads in Jmeter using CSV data set config

Tags: jmeter

How to login multiple users with different input in different threads in Jmeter using CSV data set config?
I have added CSV data set config but the thread is picking only the first entry and i m not able to see the responses for other user login

Answer (score 2):

If you use CSV data set config which contains parameterized values which users(threads) will use while running script.

below is snapshot of jmeter of csv data set config which contain emp.csv file which contains values like,

```
nachiket,101,test
nikhil,102,test
harish,103,test
```

which are empname,empid,passwd respectively for 3 users.
if you run test with 3 users then thread1 will pick first and 2nd thread will pick 2nd val so on and you can repeat the file if it has less values than no of threads.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide enough loops/iterations as given one iteration only CSV Data Set Config will read only the first entry.

Try putting the request you want to parametrize under a [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller), set enough loops and see whether it resolves your issue.

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) guide for more details.